# How to add custom validators to parsley.js?

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

I want to add a custom validator to parsley.js.
It should test if the specific field contains only letters. I tried to use the regexp validator but then i cant use custom errors cause i need the regex validation in other fields and then it isn't showing the custom error message correctly.

Do you have any examples how i can add a custom validator to parsley?

Thank you.

Comment: You can have a custom message for each field, thus you should be able to use the regexp validator.

Comment: You can find an example in the documentation at http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-validators-list

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this for letters only:

```
<input type="text" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-pattern="/^[a-zA-z]*$/" data-parsley-pattern-message="Only letters are allowed." />
```